# WFLYCTL0184: New missing/unsatisfied dependencies wildfly 10

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, wildfly

I exported war archive that I would like to deploy. I use JPA inside, with a persistence unit.

I added datasource tag inside my `standalone.xml` file like that :

```
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/bdd_colis" pool-name="bdd_colis_pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
```

And when I start my server, it return me the error specified in the title with the followin output :

```
 ...
    23:20:28,069 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
    23:20:28,134 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
    23:20:28,134 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
    23:20:28,229 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
    23:20:28,387 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
    23:20:28,388 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/bdd_colis]
    23:20:28,633 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /home/calliste/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
    23:20:28,638 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
    23:20:28,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/calliste/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments
    23:20:28,869 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
    23:20:28,897 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
    23:20:28,936 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
    23:20:28,937 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
    23:20:28,938 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
    23:20:28,939 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
    23:20:28,938 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
    23:20:28,940 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
    23:20:29,065 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6) 
    23:20:31,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for bdd_colis
    23:20:31,410 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
    23:20:31,463 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
    23:20:31,541 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'ColisDao' in deployment unit 'deployment "dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"' are as follows:

        java:global/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ColisDao!dataRecovery.ColisDao
        java:app/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ColisDao!dataRecovery.ColisDao
        java:module/ColisDao!dataRecovery.ColisDao
        java:global/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ColisDao
        java:app/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ColisDao
        java:module/ColisDao

    23:20:31,696 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
    23:20:31,703 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
    23:20:31,741 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
    23:20:31,742 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
    23:20:31,889 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)
    23:20:32,320 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
    23:20:32,392 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {
        "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.DataSource"],
        "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
            "jboss.persistenceunit.\"dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#bdd_colis\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.DataSource]",
            "jboss.persistenceunit.\"dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#bdd_colis\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.DataSource]"
        ]
    }
    23:20:32,433 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
    23:20:32,434 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
    WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
          service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.DataSource (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#bdd_colis".__FIRST_PHASE__, service jboss.persistenceunit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#bdd_colis"] 

    23:20:32,591 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
    23:20:32,591 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
    23:20:32,591 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started (with errors) in 7689ms - Started 438 of 700 services (25 services failed or missing dependencies, 405 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
    23:20:32,673 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped client-mappings cache from ejb container
    23:20:32,688 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war (runtime-name: dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war) in 66ms
    23:20:32,763 WARN  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0357: Notification of type deployment-undeployed is not described for the resource at the address []
    23:20:32,779 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /home/calliste/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/data/content/77/1bd22de0dbe2bbece064a17d0127813d1d7a66/content
    23:20:32,780 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
    23:20:32,783 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
    WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldBootstrapService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".CdiValidatorFactoryService, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 7 more ] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.WeldInstantiator, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", WFLYCTL0208: ... and 8 more ] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#bdd_colis"] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.VIEW."dataRecovery.ColisDao".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.WeldInstantiator] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".ee.ComponentRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.START, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 5 more ] 
          service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformation (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.START] 
          service jboss.naming.context.java.app."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".BeanManager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".DefaultContextService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".DefaultDataSource (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".DefaultManagedExecutorService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".DefaultManagedScheduledExecutorService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".DefaultManagedThreadFactory (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".EJBContext (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".TimerService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".TransactionSynchronizationRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UserTransaction (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.naming.context.java.module."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".env."dataRecovery.ColisDao".em (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.START, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".jndiDependencyService] 
          service jboss.persistenceunit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#bdd_colis" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START, service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT", service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".component.ColisDao.START, WFLYCTL0208: ... and 7 more ] 
          service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
          service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"] 
          service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".codec (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".session (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
          service org.wildfly.request-controller.control-point."dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT".UndertowDeploymentInfoService]
```

I would like to resolve that dependencies. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you post the whole console log?

Comment: @OuerghiYassine Hi, yes of course I juste updated my post with the complete log. Thanks for your reply

Comment: And what about the `persistence.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough points to add this as a comment, so if it answer is more suitable as a comment, please convert it...

1. Use CLI (`bin/jboss-cli.sh`), editing of XML files is not recommended anymore
2. I am almost sure, that there is a bug in your application which you are trying to deploy:

I used CLI command

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=bdd_colis:add(jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/bdd_colis",enabled=true, use-java-context=true,connection-url="jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE", driver-name=h2, user-name=sa, password=sa
```

and achieved same result in `standalone.xml`:

```xml
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/bdd_colis" pool-name="bdd_colis" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
<connection-url>
    jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
</connection-url>
<driver>h2</driver>
<security>
    <user-name>sa</user-name>
    <password>sa</password>
</security>
</datasource>
```

The dependencies errors which you are seeing are there because of a missing service. I am guessing, that somewhere in your application is defined resource named `java.jdbc.DataSource` which should be available on server and it isn't -- hence the naming context error:

```
   23:20:32,392 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.DataSource"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#bdd_colis\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.DataSource]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"dataRecovery-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#bdd_colis\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.DataSource]"
    ]
}
```

Try to prepare minimal piece of code which causes this problem and you should resolve it - or post it here.